# Using function lasdetectshape of lidR

Tags: r, point-cloud, lidr

I would like to try "lasdetectshape" in lidR package to detect line pattern objects in my point cloud.

```
library(lidR)
las <- readLAS("9a-1.las", select = 'xyzicnrRGB')

las <- lasdetectshape(las, shp_line, attribute = "Shape", filter = NULL)
```

However, getting following error:

```
Error in lasdetectshape(las, shp_line, attribute = "Shape", filter = NULL)   

could not find function "lasdetectshape"
```

I tried re-install lidR package and re-started R with no sucess.

Comment: What version of `lidR` have you got? What does `packageVersion("lidR")` say?

Comment: @Spacedman, it is 2.0.2.

Comment: This function has been introduced  in version 2.1.0. Current version is 2.1.4. 2.0.2 is 8 months old

Comment: @JRR or Spacedman please consider adding your comments as an answer so we can consider this question resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `lasdetectshape()` was introduced in version 2.1.0. You are running an old version which is 8 months old. `lidR` is a constantly evolving package. New features are regularly added, internal improvement are regularly made (memory usage and speed usually) and many bugs are fixed. Try to run an up-to-date version of the package at stay informed of the change with the [changelogs](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/blob/master/NEWS.md).